# Bootstrap Class from Accord.Net

Tags: c#, statistics, bootstrapping, statistics-bootstrap, accord.net

While attempting to `bootstrap` some data with `replacement` using `Accord.Net`, I've realised that there are not available methods that allow the extraction of simulated values, as far as I am concerned. Hence I am wondering how people manage to performing such tasks in `C#`.

So far, only the `Bootstrap. Subsamples` property retrieves the `bootstrap samples` drawn from the `population dataset` as `indices`. However I am keen on knowing the `simulated values` rather than the `indices`.

**1. Update**

So far, the closest `method` found on `Accord.Net` is:

```
Bootstrap<TModel, TInput, TOutput>
```

The main matter is that `TModel` should be a `machine learning model` type, whereas I merely look for a simulation with `replacement`.

Thus any relevant feedback on this would be very appreciated.

Best

Comment: Hi there - do you think you could post an example in the project's issue tracker of 1) what you would like to feed the project and 2) what you would like to see the project give you in return? Chances are that the project currently has the machinery to generate the simulation you need, but having a proper example of the expected input/output for the problem would make it easier to identify where it is. Thanks a lot!